# How many positive integers $\le 462$ are relatively prime to $462$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers, inclusion-exclusion

How many positive integers less than or equal to $462$ are relatively prime to $462$?

**My Approach**
Well my approach is basically that we find $|A \cup B|$ where:

- $A = \{\text{all prime numbers} \le 462\}$
- $B = \{\text{every number which isn't a factor of } 462\}$

I just don't know how to calculate this so it is not an efficient method so please answer with a more efficient method. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you deal with the prime numbers $\leqslant462$? Your question has nothing to do with prime numbers.

Comment: You should start by saying $462=2\times 3\times 7 \times 11$.  You could use inclusion-exclusion to find multiples of these primes

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos wouldn't a prime number along with 462 have a gcd of 1

Comment: Sure, but what about those non-prime numbers (such as $65$) which are also coprime with $462$?

Comment: yeah those would be the numbers which aren't the factors of 462, which I have included in my approach in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$462 = 2\times3\times7\times11$

let A be the set of integers from 1 to 462 divisible by 2

let B be the set of integers from 1 to 462 divisible by 3

let C be the set of integers from 1 to 462 divisible by 7

let D be the set of integers from 1 to 462 divisible by 11

$A\cup B\cup C\cup D$ is the set of all integers from 1 to 462 that are NOT relatively prime to 462.

So your answer will be

$462 - n(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)$

So you have to get $n(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)$. (that's just the number of elements in the union)

The pattern to get the number of elements in a union is simple. Start with $n(A)+n(B)+n(C)+n(D)$ then subtract the number of elements in the intersection of each pair... then add the number of elements in the intersection of each triple... then subtract the number of elements in the intersection of each quadruple. Described better here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

$n(A) = 462/2 = 231$... calculate all the others the same way.

Can you take it from here?

Totient function is an easier method, but I don't know if you're allowed to use that.

Comment: yep makes perfect sense... also totient function is allowed but this is fine as well

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Euler's Totient function $\phi$ is multiplicative. In other words, if we have two positive integers $a$ and $b$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, then $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b)$. So, you can use prime factorization of $462$ to divide and conquer the problem.

Comment: I don't know Euler's Totient function, I will have to read up on that

Comment: Euler's Totient Function is exactly the function $\phi(n)$ which tells us how many positive integers less than or equal to $n$ are relatively prime to $n$. You may want to understand its multiplicative property to efficiently handle these kind of problems.

Comment: okay thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, good luck :)